# Devise::SessionsController adds errors to flash, not to the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Rails: 4.0.0,
Devise: 3.0.0rc

Devise seems not to add error messages to models at all, delegating that to validations. That's fine generally. But in the case of the SessionsController, would it make sense to add the errors to the model so that you can use field_with_errors or some such functionality and say 'email is required' if the user does not put their email in.

The snippet below is where I think I would have to modify Devise to get it to add errors to the model.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)

    debugger
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

end
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on what to do? Is it even a good idea to add errors to the model on sign in via something like the following? `error.add(:model, "error message")`

It just seems that if I use the default flash[:notice] message, then I miss out on being able to attach the error messages to specific fields, which is my aim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concept is right with any other controllers except SessionsController.

Such vague information is desired for signing in activity. If an user inputted wrong information, he can only see "Invalid email or password" or something similar but not precise error.

The reason is to reduce the chance of brute signing trials.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I understand that you shouldn't reveal information about the accounts you have in your system, and I would ensure that the message shown would never be "that's an incorrect password". It was more in the case of "please put in a password" or "please put in an email". To notify the user that they forgot to do something, instead of claiming it was just "invalid". Invalid how? If they haven't put anything in, I should be able to tell them that they didn't do everything they should have. In the mean time I'm just using html5 form validations achieve that.

Comment: @Pedro, I understand your concern. It's possible to revise that behaviour by overriding Devise FailureApp. But I think your client side validation is good enough, no need to take more time on that.